# completely archive a TFS2012 project

Tags: tfs, backup, tfsbuild

In TFS 2012 what is the best practice to fully archive a TFS project? Our TFS database has gotten ridiculously large and we need to start archiving things (but of course we do not want to loose anything).

I would like to take an abandoned project form the TFS server and completely back it up to an *external* drive with all its files and its history, workitems and build definitions and then remove all of that from the TFS server.

If an abandoned project needs to be reactivated, I would like to bring that drive to the TFS server an restore that project ( with all its files and its history, workitems, build definitions and sharpoint sites), even if the original collection and the users of that project do not exist anymore and ideally even if we have upgraded to a newer version of TFS in the meantime.

What is Microsoft's idea to deal with such a scenario in TFS?

Comment: Any remarks or further questions based on the answer I provided?

Answer (score 4):

This is a really hard to execute scenario, but the official way is to split the project collection and then detach the one containing the items to be archived.

To do so, clone the project collection, remove the project you want to archive from the original, remove all projects you want to keep from the clone, then detach the clone for storage.

When you need to rehydrate the old project, you can attach it as a new project collection, it's really hard to merge it back into the old project collection after the split.

[The procedure for splitting is explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936158.aspx).

Alternatively you can use the [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools/Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to sync the project to a clean team project and backup that. You can also use these tools to re-integrate the project into the old project collection.

**Important note**

Since Build Definitions are linked to a Project Collection, not a Project, it's not really straightforward to backup/restore those. Any Lab Management settings might also need to be re-created when doing a restore procedure.

Also, any work item links that link across Team Projects, or branch/merges across team projects will get disconnected with this procedure.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible in VS Online?

Comment: No, currently not possible.