# TFS 2015 Archive

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have a TFS 2015 installation where we have a rather big number of projects. Currently there are old projects, that aren't used anymore but need to stay available as an archive (read only).

I'd like to make a workspace or something in TFS so that these projects normally don't come up in the normal view.

One way I found out is to set the TFS offline, make a copy of the database, bring the copy of the database online and then delete all projects that are still active and rename it. After that bring back online the original database and delete all archived projects.

This can be done once. Maybe once a year, but it will result in a large number of databases. This will make it worse than leaving the inactive projects in the workspace.

Does anyone have better idea? Or: What do you do with old projects?

Answer (score 1):

First, there currently is no archiving function on TFS. However you can use something else as a workaround. To do this, you can either create a project designated as archived that you then have to assign permissions to and so on or move the project into another collection using the TFS Integration Toolkit.

Set the **Read** permission to **Deny** of contributor group will hidden the collection to come up in the normal view.

Below are some related blogs for your reference:

- [How to: Archive Team Foundation Server Team Projects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfsalm/2014/05/26/how-to-archive-team-foundation-server-team-projects/)
- [completely archive a TFS2012 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006762/completely-archive-a-tfs2012-project)

Moreover, there has been a feature request in [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10145889-add-a-nice-way-to-archive-tfs-projects), you can also vote up it to get more  attention.

Answer (score 0):

The process you are using (cloning a collection) would be the only method to achieve an archive as you describe it.

I would start by understanding why you have so many projects! Prefer larger Team Projects that contain many Products, Projects, Teams that are easier to manage.

Comment: I got a little bit confused with the notation: There is one project with many teams in it in the TFS. Internally I call them projects.

Comment: You cant split a team project